# Document scanning using AngularJS with .Net Core(v3.1)

Tags: .net, scanning, angularjs

I'm building angularJS application with .NET Core for document scanning and viewing a documents. I have looked at offerings from multiple providers like dynamosoft, asprise, atalasoft etc. Please let me know other providers which are support for AngularJS + .NET Core(v3.1).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The LEADTOOLS SDK provides a [Web-Scanning library](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/twain/html5-web-scanning) that implements TWAIN(Windows) or SANE(Linux) scanning through .NET components implemented in a web service. The .NET components are also available as NuGet packages from nuget.org and can be used in a .NET Core project.

An online demo is available from the LEADTOOLS website [here](http://demo.leadtools.com/javascript/ScanningDemo/). When trying this demo, note that it searches for the scanning web service before prompting to download an installer that will set up the web service.

The toolkit also provides a [JS Document Viewer](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/document/document-viewer-html5) which allows for the display of documents in browser through interaction with a .NET document service. An online demo for this is also available [here](https://demo.leadtools.com/JavaScript/DocumentViewer/index.html).

The projects for the scanning web service, the JS web scanning viewer, and the JS document viewer  in the demo can be found in the free evaluation of the toolkit, available from the website [here](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads).

Edit: Added Disclaimer: I work for the vendor of this toolkit.

Comment: Are you affiliated with Leadtools in any way?  If so, you ***must*** disclose your affiliation (in full) within your answer and are advised to read this: https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2933/is-leadtools-spamming

Comment: Apologies, I have added a disclaimer